# How do i convert a given xml using xslt to something as below

Tags: xml, xslt

If i have a problem like given below

i need to convert the XML using an XSLT to produuce `<parent.child>value</parent.child>`   and  `<parent.child.grandchild>value</parent.child.grandchild>` if granchild exists.
also if i dont want a particular element say price it shouldnt be printed...help me make the XSLT please?
It should be a generic code such that for any XML it would produce the below output..
  we should get something like this.......

```
<food.name>Strawberry Belgian Waffles</food.name>
    <food.description>
    Light Belgian waffles covered with strawberries and whipped cream
    </food.description>
    <food.calories>900</food.calories>`
and so on..
```

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<breakfast_menu>
<food>
    <name>Belgian Waffles</name>
    <price>$5.95</price>
    <description>
   Two of our famous Belgian Waffles with plenty of real maple syrup
   </description>
    <calories>650</calories>
</food>
<food>
    <name>Strawberry Belgian Waffles</name>
    <price>$7.95</price>
    <description>
    Light Belgian waffles covered with strawberries and whipped cream
    </description>
    <calories>900</calories>
</food>
<food>
    <name>Berry-Berry Belgian Waffles</name>
    <price>$8.95</price>
    <description>
    Belgian waffles covered with assorted fresh berries and whipped cream
    </description>
    <calories>900</calories>
</food>
<food>
    <name>French Toast</name>
    <price>$4.50</price>
    <description>
    Thick slices made from our homemade sourdough bread
    </description>
    <calories>600</calories>
</food>
<food>
    <name>Homestyle Breakfast</name>
    <price>$6.95</price>
    <description>
    Two eggs, bacon or sausage, toast, and our ever-popular hash browns
    </description>
    <calories>950</calories>
</food>
</breakfast_menu>
```

Comment: If it's generic, then I would expect to see `<breakfast_menu.food.name>` as the result in your example. -- P.S. Please state if using XSLT 1.0 or 2.0.

Comment: No ill select breakfast as the start node so it shouldnt be included.

Comment: No priority on the XSLT version...

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "ill select breakfast as the start node". You cannot select anything in XSLT. It's a set of instructions for processing the input XML. If you want to exclude the root element's name from being included in the compound names of its descendants, then this will apply to ALL root elements in all XML documents processed by the stylesheet.

Comment: could you show me how its done ?

Comment: My answer shows how it's done.

Answer (score 0):

The following stylesheet:

**XSLT 2.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="*">
    <xsl:element name="{ancestor::*[parent::*]/concat(name(), '.')}{name()}">
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

applied to your example input, will return:

**Result**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<breakfast_menu>
      <food>
            <food.name>Belgian Waffles</food.name>
            <food.price>$5.95</food.price>
            <food.description>
       Two of our famous Belgian Waffles with plenty of real maple syrup
       </food.description>
            <food.calories>650</food.calories>
      </food>
      <food>
            <food.name>Strawberry Belgian Waffles</food.name>
            <food.price>$7.95</food.price>
            <food.description>
        Light Belgian waffles covered with strawberries and whipped cream
        </food.description>
            <food.calories>900</food.calories>
      </food>
      <food>
            <food.name>Berry-Berry Belgian Waffles</food.name>
            <food.price>$8.95</food.price>
            <food.description>
        Belgian waffles covered with assorted fresh berries and whipped cream
        </food.description>
            <food.calories>900</food.calories>
      </food>
      <food>
            <food.name>French Toast</food.name>
            <food.price>$4.50</food.price>
            <food.description>
        Thick slices made from our homemade sourdough bread
        </food.description>
            <food.calories>600</food.calories>
      </food>
      <food>
            <food.name>Homestyle Breakfast</food.name>
            <food.price>$6.95</food.price>
            <food.description>
        Two eggs, bacon or sausage, toast, and our ever-popular hash browns
        </food.description>
            <food.calories>950</food.calories>
      </food>
</breakfast_menu>
```

---

If you don't want an element such as `price` to be included, simply add an empty template matching it.

Comment: and when I tried to execute your solution on http://www.utilities-online.info/xsltransformation/#.XFJYglwzbIU it says it isnt valid!!!

Comment: @sachinroyston When I ask you to state which version you will be using, it's because the solution will be different according to your answer. When I put **XSLT 2.0** above my code, it's because it will not work in XSLT 1.0. -- Note also that SO is not a coding service. The answer above shows a method to produce the concatenated element names - which I think is the difficult problem here. It is not meant to perform unrelated secondary tasks which you should be able to implement yourself.